# Integrating node modules and JavaScript into our Web API controller calls

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-web-api, module

Our main backend server is a .net 5 web API project. I'm needing to integrate some javascript modules and javascript code into our functionality. I'm wanting to save on the time of rewriting these modules all into c# to access from our code. Are there any packages or methods to accomplish this or am I best of running a separate node server for this functionality?

Comment: Just for curious read , here is an interesting article https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/blazor-javascript-isolation-modules-and-dynamic-csharp

Answer (score 8):

### Option 1. Access A Node.js Server Script From C#/.Net 5

[Jering.Javascript.NodeJS](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS) enables you to invoke javascript in a Node.js module from C#. With this ability, you can use Node.js scripts/modules from within your C# projects. Supports: Callbacks, Promises and Async/Await. Get js scripts via file path, string or stream. You can run a single global instance of your Node.js App that remains in memory or create a new instance for each call. See an example on [Invoking Javascript From File](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS#invoking-javascript-from-a-file).

Install Via Package Manager or .Net CLI

```bash
Install-Package Jering.Javascript.NodeJS
#or
dotnet add package Jering.Javascript.NodeJS
```

some-module.js

```js
module.exports = {
    doSomething: (callback, message) => callback(null, { message: message + '!' }),
    doSomethingElse: (callback, message) => callback(null, { message: message + '.' })
}
```

In your .Net App

```csharp
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddNodeJS();
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
INodeJSService nodeJSService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<INodeJSService>();

public class Result {
  public string? Message { get; set; }
}
Result? result = await nodeJSService.InvokeFromFileAsync<Result>("some-module.js", "doSomething", args: new[] { "success" });
Assert.Equal("success!", result?.Message);
```

This is a basic implementation example. You should see the [Jering.Javascript.NodeJS](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS) Docs for complete examples of installation, configuration and usage.

---

### Option 2. HTTP REST / Web Socket

Create an HTTP Rest or WebSocket Wrapper around your JS scripts and call them from the .Net App. In your .Net App, use [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient#make-http-requests) to make HTTP requests. Then over in Node.js wrap your scripts with routes to access various methods.  Something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/some/endpoint', (req, res) => {
  // Gets executed when the URL http://localhost:3000/some/endpoint
  // Do your thing here 
  // Return it back to .Net with:
  res.send(JSON.stringify({some_response: "Hello There"}))
});

// Start the http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Using the HTTP Rest/WebSocket option will require that you already have your node.js app running (and keep it running) before you attempt to call the endpoints from .Net.

---

### Option 3. Execute Standard Javascript Embedded Scripts

Here are the most popular .Net modules that will allow you to run Standard Javascript code within your C# .Net Service. However, these both execute your JS Scripts using the **V8 Engine** and will not work for Node.js specific methods such as FileSystem. These will also not allow the use of require() or Import. This might be a good option if you have very limited Javascript needs and will not be adding additional JS functions in the future.

1. [Microsoft.ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript)
2. [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)
3. [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net)

This option is quick and simple for very small scripts, but would be the most difficult to update and maintain your JS scripts.